# Get first dimension in multidimension array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, fill

Please see the MWE:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    vector< vector<size_t> > a(2, vector<size_t>(3));
    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 1;


    a[1][0] = 2;
    a[1][1] = 2;
    a[1][2] = 2;  

    fill(a[0].begin(), a[0].end(), 0);


    return 0;
}
```

Here I reset the first row of my 2x3 matrix to the value zero by using `fill`. But how do I reset the first column?

Comment: It is usually more efficient if you use vector of vectors as `[y][x]` instead of `[x][y]`

Answer (score 2):

One way is:

```
for (auto &row: a)
    row[0] = 0;
```

The vector of vectors doesn't have any particular structure other than being a vector of vectors, i.e. there's no builtin way to get a view on a column. If you regularly want to do this then consider using a (non-standard) class which represents a Matrix.

Answer (score 2):

In c++ you don't actually have a matrix, you have a vector of vectors, so there is no single operation that can lead to the result you're looking for, as you need to access every single "column" vector when modifying them.
Instead, use a for cycle.

```
for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) a[i][0] = 0;
```

You could also place it in an helper function

```
void resetColumn(vector<vector<size_t>>& a, int col)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < a.size(); i++) a[i][col] = 0; 
}
```

and call it from your main when you need to

```
int main()
{
    vector< vector<size_t> > a(2, vector<size_t>(3));
    a[0][0] = 1;
    a[0][1] = 1;
    a[0][2] = 1;


    a[1][0] = 2;
    a[1][1] = 2;
    a[1][2] = 2;  

    resetColumn(a, 1);


    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT**: Typos

Comment: I was in a hurry and didn't test, I just missed a & in front of the vector passed to the function

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int rw = 0;rw<ar.size();rw++)
       a[rw][0] = 0;
```